# dashboard layout pattern

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to position two buttons one below the other one with some padding. Unfortunately, the bottom one fills up the whole screen and goes behind the top one. :-S

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:padding="6dip">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/gallery" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:scaleType="centerInside" 
            android:id="@+id/gallery_btn"></ImageButton> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/camera_btn" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camera" 
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: turns out the ADT eclipse plugin has a messed up graphical previewer. The buttons display correctly on a real device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a short blog post about dashboard implementation that you might (hopefully) find helpful. You will find ready code from here too:
http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/01/implementing-dashboard-and-action-bar.html

Answer (score 5):

Roman Nurik (@romannurik) has written a  custom Dashboard Layout class that simplifies creating a Dashboard: You can find it at https://gist.github.com/882650

Comment: how to use this class?